# Rails create callback for 2 dependent resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I want to know how i can use create callback like before_create or after_create for the two dependent models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Lets suppose i have two models called User and Member and i want to create a member whenever any user will be created and want to create user whenever any member will be created .

If i will use the after_create or before_create callback in both the models it will run as never ending loop .so how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if either of the association exists in db before creating it in `after_create` callback, something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_member

  private
    def create_member
      unless self.member?
        # create member
      end
    end
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_user

  private
    def create_user
      unless self.user?
        # create user
      end
    end
end
```